# AG Grid Disable ContextMenu from API call

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

I have a simple context menu on an ag-grid, `Alert`, which when clicked calls a method `alertOne()`

```
getContextMenuItems(params: GetContextMenuItemsParams): (string | MenuItemDef)[] {
    var result: (string | MenuItemDef)[] = [
      {
        // custom item
        name: 'Alert ',
        action: () => {
          this.alertOne(params.value);
        }
      }      
    ];
    return result;
  }
}

alertOne(value: string) {
    window.alert('Alerting about ' + value);
}
```

I want to disable the Alert menu button based on the result of an API call ie:

```
{
    name: 'Alert ',
    action: () => {
        this.alertOne(params.value);
    },
    disabled: this.checkUserIsValid()
}

public checkUserIsValid() {

    return this.httpClient.get('my-url....', {responseType: 'json' as 'json')

}
```

The API call returns either true/false. However when running the above, the http GET is never made.

Answer (score 1):

As per [interface](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/context-menu/#reference-accessories-getContextMenuItems) `disabled` is a boolean flag. So when you provide your callback `this.checkUserIsValid()` it is treated as `true` value, I guess.

Maybe you can check if a user is valid in advance, and then set some property?